# Running Excel macro from Outlook macro getting error 1004

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, runtime-error

I have a rule in Outlook which is running a VBA script. This VBA is to open a local Excel file, and run the macro in the Excel file.

When running, and opening the Excel file, I'm getting the error:
Run-time error 1004: Cannot run the macro 'Ask me question workflow.xlsm!AskMeFlow'. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled.

When running the Excel macro from Excel, all is running fine.

My code in Outlook:

```
Sub AskMeAlerts()

    Dim appExcel As Excel.Application
    Dim wkb As Excel.Workbook

    Set appExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    appExcel.Workbooks.Open ("C:\Ask me question workflow.xlsm")

    appExcel.Visible = True

    appExcel.Run "Ask me question workflow.xlsm!AskMeFlow"

    appExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close

    appExcel.Quit

    Set appExcel = Nothing
    Set wkb = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to surround the workbook name in `'` single quotes:

```
appExcel.Run "'Ask me question workflow.xlsm'!AskMeFlow"
```

You can get away without the `'` single quotes when your workbook name doesn't contain spaces, but yours does.

Comment: + 1 You are on fire!:)

Answer (score 0):

Outlook 2010 running Excel 2010 macros seems to need the single quotes (see earlier answer) even if the workbook name doesn't contain spaces. What worked in Office 2003 wouldn't work in 2010 without them.